# Calculate correlation in Excel after matching on a column

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I need to calculate correlations for multiple years. The trick is in selecting appropriate rows from 2 columns after matching values a third column.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CORREL() formula as an array formula:

```
=CORREL(IF($A$2:$A$12 = E2,$B$2:$B$12),IF($A$2:$A$12 = E2,$C$2:$C$12))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]